# How to handle routing with two actions with the same number of paramaters in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ActionLink to show parameters in URL instead of querystring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499320/actionlink-to-show-parameters-in-url-instead-of-querystring)

I have the following routes:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
          "List", // Route name
          "{Home}/{list}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
          new { 
              controller = "Home", 
              action = "List", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
              name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
      );

 routes.MapRoute(
          "Details", // Route name
          "{Home}/{details}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
          new { 
              controller = "Home", 
              action = "Details", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
              name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
      );
```

I am trying for:

/home/list/1/a
/home/details/2/b

The above results in home/details/2?name=b

Comment: I think you are confusing parameter defaults with route portions. Those are the same route, but with different defaults. [Why not try the routing debugger?](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx)

Comment: Is this not a duplicate to your other question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you haven't gotten your code example wrong, You can't.

The route handler will pick the 1st route that matches.

However, from what it looks like what you actually want is this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
          "List", // Route name
          "home/list/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
          new { 
              controller = "Home", 
              action = "List", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
              name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
      );

 routes.MapRoute(
          "Details", // Route name
          "home/details/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
          new { 
              controller = "Home", 
              action = "Details", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
              name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
      );
```

In fact, those two are similar enough that it can be distilled into 1 route

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          "Details", // Route name
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
          new { 
              controller = "Home", 
              action = "List", 
              id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
              name = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid creating a route with two UrlParameter.Optional declarations.

You can achieve your routing by adding one route above the default route, like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Id_Name", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
        new{
            controller = "Home",
            action = "List"  } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "List",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
);
```

The first route will create the URL you want for when both variables are declared.  The second route will work for either one variable or no variables.