# ActionLink to show parameters in URL instead of querystring?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this route defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                   "Details", // Route name
                   "{home}/{details}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
                   new
                   {
                       controller = "Home",
                       action = "Details",
                       id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                       name = UrlParameter.Optional
                   } // Parameter defaults
               );
```

The ActionLink:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Show Details", "Details", "MyController", new { id = 1, name ="a" })
```

The actionlink results in `/Home/Details/1?name=a` I am after `/Home/List/1/a`

Answer (score 12):

Your route definition should be like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Details", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
    new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Details",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        name = UrlParameter.Optional
    } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Also you should use the [proper overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx):

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Show Details",             // linkText
    "Details",                  // action
    "MyController",             // controller
    new { id = 1, name = "a" }, // routeValues
    null                        // htmlAttributes
)
```

Notice the `null` at the end.

Comment: The actionlink worked fine when the above route was added before the default route. However, the default now goes to /Home/Details

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess :

probably your route was registered after the default route. Put it as first route inside your global.asax then it will work.

Like below :

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
                           "Details", // Route name
                           //Put action instead of details
                           "{home}/{action}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
                           new
                           {
                               controller = "Home",
                               action = "Details",
                               id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                               name = UrlParameter.Optional
                           } // Parameter defaults
                       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

**UPDATE**

@Simon is correct, but you can use another way if you want.

In order for the route to work only for one action method, use following code.

Create a constraint as follows :

```
public class EqualConstraint : IRouteConstraint {

    private string _match = String.Empty;

    public EqualConstraint(string match) {

        _match = match;
    }

    public bool Match(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {

        return string.Equals(values[parameterName].ToString(), _match);
    }
}
```

And then change your route like below :

```
    routes.MapRoute(
                       "Details", // Route name
                       //Put action instead of details
                       "{home}/{action}/{id}/{name}", // URL with parameters
                       new
                       {
                           controller = "Home",
                           action = "Details",
                           id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                           name = UrlParameter.Optional
                       }, // Parameter defaults
                       new { 
                          controller = new EqualConstraint("Home"),
                          action = new EqualConstraint("Details")
                       }
                   );
```

Comment: @Danny what do you mean by "the default now goes to /Home/Details"?

Comment: When the application starts its goes to /Home/Details instead of the default route /Home/Index

Comment: that's because you marked id & name as optional, so it matches if they're blank.

Comment: @SimonHalsey is correct but also see my updated answer for another solution. (not the best one in this case but it might come in handy sometimes)