# How to remove ? and = from MVC url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-routing

Hi this my ActionLink

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <h3>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Post", new { postId = item.Id, postSlug = item.UrlSlug })
            </h3>
        </div>
    }
```

and also this is Post action result

```
 public ActionResult Post(Guid postId, string postSlug)
        {
            var post = _blogRepository.GetPostById(postId);
            return View("Post", post);
        }
```

and finally I have defined this route in global.asax to support the above action

```
 routes.MapRoute("PostSlugRoute", "Blog/{Post}/{postId}/{postSlug}",
                            new
                                {
                                    controller = "Blog",
                                    action = "Post",
                                    postId = "",
                                    postSlug = ""
                                });
```

what I get in Url is this

```
http://localhost:1245/Blog/Post?postId=554c78f1-c712-4613-9971-2b5d7ca3e017&postSlug=another-goos-post
```

but I don't like this ! I expect something like this

```
http://localhost:1245/Blog/Post/554c78f1-c712-4613-9971-2b5d7ca3e017/another-goos-post
```

what should I do to achieve this ??

Comment: You'll probably want to add appropriate tags to your question if you want people to see it.

Comment: for example, you might want to tag ASP.Net and C# or VB, and which version of MVC

Comment: You have to add a matching route to your routestable else it creates them as querystring

Comment: could you please tell me more about that , or give an example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499320/actionlink-to-show-parameters-in-url-instead-of-querystring this should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Route definition to not have Post be a parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute("PostSlugRoute",
    "Blog/Post/{postId}/{postSlug}", // Removed the {} around Post
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post", postId = "", postSlug = "" }
);
```

And ensure your route is above MVC's Default route.

**UPDATE**: Updating with exact examples I used

*global.asax*

```
routes.MapRoute("PostSlugRoute",
    "Blog/Post/{postId}/{postSlug}", // Removed the {} around Post
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post", postId = "", postSlug = "" }
);
```

*~/Views/Blog/Post.cshtml*

```
@{
    Guid id = Guid.Parse("554c78f1-c712-4613-9971-2b5d7ca3e017");
    string slug = "another-goos-post";
    string title = "Another Goos Post";
}
@Html.ActionLink(title, "Post", new { postId = id, postSlug = slug })
```

Comment: Then you've got something else interfering with your routing, because I copied and pasted that code from a running MVC project after testing it to make sure I had it right. You need to make sure the route is ABOVE the default route, that's the only thing I can think of that might cause problems.

Comment: yes it is , I've removed MVC default route and this route is the first

Comment: I've modified the question with the exact code from the test I did, it should work. Also make sure you can actually get the page to load if you manually go to `~/Blog/Post/554c78f1-c712-4613-9971-2b5d7ca3e017/another-goos-post`

Comment: yeah you were right , I just test it in a separate application , it is true ,what the hell is going with my code , Godddddddddddd!