# ASP.NET MVC Routing doesn't affect the changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using Asp.Net MVC3 and wanna to define a custom route, I test my route in other project and it works well but in main project it doesn't!
as I made a question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365605/how-to-remove-and-from-mvc-url)
it is so interesting that I comment all of my defined route , but it still works as before! 
(my project doesn't look to my Routing !)
is it possible to MVC to render any page in this case ??? I have done like this

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

          //  RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
          //    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            // Initializer
            Database.SetInitializer(new Initializer());


            //Ninject
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectDependencyResolver());
        }
```

Notice about this line of code that is comment !

```
   //    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

I think something has override my MVC routing that any change in my Routing doesn't affect in My project ,what is the problem with that ??

Comment: Are you using Areas? Because the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` register the are rountes.. are you sure that you run the latest version where the `RegisterRoutes` is commented out? Have you tried after a clean/rebuild?

Comment: yeah I have an area ,but it is the same normal running when I comment it