# How to generate URL using Html.ActionLink with Forward Slashes instead of QuestionMark

Tags: c#, razor, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to generate the URL with forward slash like the following

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.StudentID, name = item.FirstName })
```

**Desired Result:**

```
http://www.example.com/Students/Details/3/ttcg
http://www.example.com/Students/Details/4/john
http://www.example.com/Students/Details/5/ronaldo
```

**Current Result:**

```
http://www.example.com/Students/Details/3?name=ttcg
```

**Controller Action using RouteAttribute**

```
[Route("Students/Details/{id}/{name?}")]
    public ActionResult Details(int? id, string name)
    {
        if (id.HasValue == false)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Student student = _studentService.GetDetail(id.Value);
        if (student == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        student.FirstName += name;
        return View(student);
    }
```

Currently, I cheated by using this code to get the desired result.

```
<a href="Students/Details/@item.StudentID/@item.FirstName" >Details</a>
```

Is there a better way to generate the desired url like I want?

According to this post [URL With RouteConfig.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299337/actionlink-is-showing-query-string-instead-of-url-parameters), do I have to add a new route in RouteConfig file?  Does it mean that RouteAttribute does not support this kind of URL generation?

Comment: Is not working after changing RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: I haven't changed RouteConfig.cs yet.  But I would like to make sure before doing it.  Since I am already using RouteAttribute, I don't want to declare it again in RouteConfig.cs

Comment: You can change routes.MapRoute and try, whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Enable attribute routing in RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

after adding this you will get desired result.